Does a dependency exclusions remove Transitive Dependencies belonging to transitive dependencies
If I have a pom.xml setup with exclusions as:
<dependency>
  <groupId>eg1</groupId>
  <artifactId>ea1</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>g1</groupId>
  <artifactId>a1</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.3</version>
  <exclusions>
      ...
      <exclusion>
          <groupId>eg1</groupId>
          <artifactId>ea1</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
</dependency>

And lets say the artifact a1 has a transitive dependency: a2 which has ea1 as its own transitive dependency(with another version, say, 2). So the hierarchy tree looks like this:
>> a1 (dependency)
>> >> ea1 (transitive dependency of a1 with version 1)
>> >> a2 (transitive dependency of a1)
>> >> >> ea1 (transitive dependency of a2 with version 2)

Will the exclusion setup exclude ea1 version 2 since its a transitive dependency of a transitive dependency?

What does this have to do with JDBC?

You can also use mvn dependency:tree to see what happens when your dependency declarations change.

Yes. Exclusions work regardless of the level of transitivity of the excluded dependency.
